# ¿Puedo recrear mi aplicación Android en Flutter?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, flutter

Tengo una app en Google Play Store programada con Android nativo en ANDROID STUDIO, publicada, conservo su llave para actualizaciones, PERO, quiero hacer la nueva versión de esta app desde cero en FLUTTER, y así tenerla disponible para iOS, entre otros beneficios que me ofrece Flutter, se que debo usar el mismo nombre de paquete, pero...

**No se como crear la app nueva, y utilizar la clave de la anterior, si alguien tiene conocimiento POR FAVOR!**

Comment: Tu pregunta es amplia, lo cual ocasionará su cierre, trata de extraer la mayor información posible, consulta libros, herramientas, etc

Answer (score 0):

Hola @alexdotel claro que puedes recrear el app desde 0 en Flutter. Debes asegurarte que después de crear el proyecto Flutter le asignes el package name adecuado al proyecto nuevo de Android.

Para programar Flutter puedes utilizar VS Code o incluso el mismo Android Studio. Puedes consultar la documentación del Framework en español aquí: https://esflutter.dev/docs/ . Personalmente creo que la documentación disponible ahora es muy buena y te ayudará a empezar con el refactor de tu app. Te deseo los mejores éxitos.